# How to mock inline controller on directive?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

When testing you can mock a controller that has been registered with `angular.module(...).controller('MyCtrl')` by using `$controllerProvider.register('MyCtrl')`.

But how can I mock an inline controller on a directive?

```
function MyCtrl() {

}

function MyDir() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controllerAs: 'myCtrl',
        controller: MyCtrl,
        template: '<div>hi</div>',
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible without something really hacky. Instead, declare the controller as normal and reference it from the directive by name.

```
angular.module(...).controller('MyCtrl')
```

directive:

```
return {
    // ...
    controller: 'MyCtrl',
    // ...
};
```

This also allows you to test the controller like any other controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is very late, but it actually is possible:

```js
angular
    .module( 'myModule' )
    .directive( 'myDir', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            bindToController: true,
            controllerAs: '$ctrl',
            controller: MyDirController,
            scope: {}
        };
    });

function MyDirController( ... ) { ... }
    
...
    
let myDir = $injector.get( 'myDirDirective' ); //Returns an array of registrations
let $controller = $injector.get( '$controller' );
//Since we expect only a single registration, we can use the first element
let $ctrl = $controller( myDir[0].controller, { /*locals*/}, {/*bindings*/});
```